# Mixed Content Error

Tags: php, wordpress, css

Few days back,i installed SSL certificate to my site for securing my site  but now I'm getting the below error while inspecting my page
Mixed Content:The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I could not find the url in my theme's function.php or header.php
I'm using

> The7 — Responsive Multi-Purpose WordPress Theme

Does anybody have idea about it

Comment: Change the URL to use https for the stylesheet.

Comment: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700`

Just add the `s` onto the `http`

Answer (score 0):

Since your site uses https, you must include all the resources like, js, css, images etc from https otherwise you will get error.

For fix your problem, just change the url `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700`

to

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700`

Comment: thats is the problem, i could not find the url .i looked in function.php and header.php files .Do you have some idea

Comment: Search inside your complete project files

Comment: i just realized that it gets imported from somewhere @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700); Do you know what is this

Comment: To find the urls being loaded over http , this video may help : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDgPzQXSm-A